# NSDragOperation for drag vom NSTableView is -1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsdragginginfo, nsdraggingitem

Simple setup:

I've got an `NSTableView` that allows items to be dragged to an `NSView` subclass.

In the view I'm checking the drag operation via `NSDraggingInfo`'s method `draggingSourceOperationMask`.

Drops received there have a `NSDragOperation` of **-1**. Drags started from the view have expected drag operations (move, copy, depending on the circumstances). But drags from the table view are totally screwed up. Any idea what's going on there..?

Anything I can do from `- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes` ?

Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**D'oh!!**

Forgot to call `setDraggingSourceOperationMask:forLocal:` on the `NSTableView` to configure it.
('[*Sets the default operation mask returned by draggingSourceOperationMaskForLocal: to mask.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setDraggingSourceOperationMask%3aforLocal%3a)')

Alas, hope that'll help some other poor soul to save some time when googling the hive mind..